# simulating projectile velocity

Tags: c#, .net, xna, monogame

I'm making a top-down 2d shooting game in Monogame/XNA, and I want to accurately simulate a projectile's movement over time (per frame), and detect its velocity at the time when it collides with another object or the ground (given the projectile's angle, initial velocity, mass, and drag).

I've found some equations which look right, but they mostly go over my head in terms of actual implementation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You begin by making an interface for your game objects like

```
public abstract class PhyObj
{
    Vector2 v;//Velocity
    Vector2 x;//Position
    float Mass; //If mass is going to be constant, you can make this readonly
    float Drag; //The Drag/friction
    Rectangle Dest;// The position of this Object in the game screen
    Texture2D texture;// The image/sprite for this object

    void Update(Vector2 acc)//acc is the acceleration inputted at a given time
    {
        a=a-(v*Drag); //Adjust actual acceleration with the drag involved
        v+=a;// dv/dt = a
        x+=v;// dx/dt = v

        //Adjust the position of the rectangle
        Dest.X=(int)x.X;
        Dest.Y=(int)x.Y;
    }
    void Draw(SpriteBatch s)
    {
        s.Draw(texture,Dest,Color.White);
    }
}
```

Next, have a list of IPhyObj that you will be maintaining.

```
LinkedList<IPhyObj> Components;
```

Your `Draw` method of the game class will have something like

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gt)
{
    spritebatch.Begin();
    foreach(var item in Components)item.Draw(spritebatch);
    spritebatch.End();
}
```

The `Update` method of the game class will be similar, along with the collision detection and handling that would be implemented.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gt)
{
    //Update every object's position
    foreach(var item in Components)
    {
        Vector2 accinput=Vector2.Zero
        //Do something to compute the Acceleration vector
        item.Update(accinput);
    }


    //Collision management
    foreach(var item1 in Components)
    {
        foreach(var item2 in Components)
        {
            if(item1!=item2 && item1.Dest.Intersects(item2.Dest))//Collision deteted!
            {
                //Handle Collision. I am treating it as an elastic collision here

                var v1 = (((item1.Mass-item2.Mass)/(item1.Mass+item2.Mass))*item1.v) + (((2*item2.Mass)/(item1.Mass+item2.Mass))*item2.v);

                var v2 = v1 + item1.v - item2.v;

                item1.v= v1;
                item2.v= v2;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very basic implementation. I typed this without testing so let me know if it works.

I have implemented a collision between Rectangle as it is simple to handle. If you need collision between circles, I suggest you read a bit on elastic collision and its required 2D equations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision

Comment: I'll let you know when I've tested this out

Comment: if the projectile is fast enough and the framerate is low enough. the projectile will pass right through objects without colliding with them. It is better to draw a line(ray) from the projectile and infinity in the direction of it's velocity. Then find the nearest intersection along that line, then use that to decide if it will collide with the object within the next frame.